# Font size does not change

Tags: html, sass

When the screen width is reduced to 824px, the font should change its size, but this does not happen. I can't change anything with size reduction in li.

But at the same time `header__header` changes its size.

**html:**

```
<section class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="header__list">
                    <li class="header__item"><a class="header__link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="header__item"><a class="header__link" href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="header__item"><a class="header__link" href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li class="header__item"><a class="header__link" href="#">Recommendations</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h1 class="header__header">
                    Reptile - nursery with snakes, lizards, and other cold-blooded.
                </h1>
                <button class="header__button">Learn more</button>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**styles.scss:**

```
.header__list {
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 200px;
        .header__link {
            font-size: 20px;
            position: relative;
            &:before {
                content: '';
                width: 100%;
                height: 1px;
                background-color: white;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                bottom: -5px;
                transform: scaleX(0);
                transition: 0.2s;
            }
            &:hover::before {
                transform: scaleX(1);
                transition: transform 0.2s;
            }
        }
    }
```

**adaptive.sccs:**

```
@media (max-width:824px) {
    .header {
        .header__item {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The posted media query doesn't contain *anything* that could cause a change of font-size anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you use "clamp" in your CSS allows you to set a responsive font size that adapts based on the viewport width. The "clamp" function takes three parameters: a minimum value, a preferred value based on a viewport unit (such as vw for viewport width), and a maximum value.

```
.header__list {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 200px;

    .header__link {
        font-size: clamp(16px, 4vw, 20px); /* Adjust the min, viewport unit, and max values as needed */
        position: relative;

        &:before {
            content: '';
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: -5px;
            transform: scaleX(0);
            transition: 0.2s;
        }

        &:hover::before {
            transform: scaleX(1);
            transition: transform 0.2s;
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: 824px) {
    .header {
        .header__link {
            font-size: clamp(12px, 3vw, 16px); /* Adjust the min, viewport unit, and max values as needed */
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```